# NetSuite Sales Order. Update a field for some line items

Tags: php, soap, netsuite

PHP & NS2015_2 SDK. Want to update a field for some items in Sales Order. Let's say we want to update amount for second line/item in list.

My code sample below:

```
$Service = new NetSuiteService($Config);
$SalesOrder = new SalesOrder();
$SalesOrder->internalId = 234234;
$OrderItem = new SalesOrderItem();
$OrderItem->line = 2;
$OrderItem->amount = 222;
$SalesOrder->itemList = new SalesOrderItemList();
$SalesOrder->itemList->replaceAll = false;
$SalesOrder->itemList->item = [$OrderItem];
$Request = new UpdateRequest();
$Request->record = $SalesOrder;
$Response = $Service->update($Request);
```

Returning error is "Please choose an item to add" meaning it try to insert a line (it expect item field) instead of updating second line.

The strange thing is if I set line to 1 it works! But i want to update second line or sometimes third, etc...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What does your request XML look like?

Comment: @iloveitaly, XML is properly formed by NS SDK, not a prob here.

Comment: Unfortunately, the PHP toolkit has a good number of bugs. It's easier to view the request/response XML and track down the problem from there.

Comment: Do you mean to talk directly to NS by forming XML "manually"?

Comment: No, you shouldn't interact with SuiteTalk with raw XML. However, to help debug the issue, it's often helpful to inspect the XML generated by the bindings library being used. Posting the XML with your question will help determine if it's a library/binding issue, a netsuite instance issue, or a netsuite API issue.

Comment: Was able to implement it by reading first entire row, and later update it whole at once. It seems NS does not support other ways.

Comment: @Marcodor are you saying it's not possible to update a single Sales Order Line Item?  Like you have to update them all at once together?

Comment: As I remember, I had to specify all column values, instead of just needed partial fields. It seems like NS treat entire row as one field value internally.

Answer (score 0):

when calling the rest api add a param `?replace=item`

`'/record/v1/salesorder/'.$netsuite_id.'?replace=item'`

and omit `$OrderItem->line = 2;`